# How can I avoid magnesium smoke during melting?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I am trying to make a [magnesium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium)-[nickel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel) alloy. I carry out the melting process in an inert gas, but during the process, the magnesium smokes. What can I do?

Comment: Ni has melting point 1455 °C, Mg has boiling point 1091 °C, so hard to advice. If Mg is immersed in liquid Ni, it would float and happily boiling. The question is, if Ni(s) sitting on the bottom of Mg below its boiling point would dissolve in Mg or not. Not sure if pressurized melting/alloying is available technology/security-wise. It could easily act as the high speed uranium anti-tank projectile when getting inside the task.

Comment: Short, laconic questions usually need a big effort and long clarification. They do not  attract useful answers, but rather votes for closure until they are more elaborated. Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: [This pdf](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=5142b21f55f9807fJmltdHM9MTY5Njk4MjQwMCZpZ3VpZD0yYjRjNTI5NS1kM2EyLTYwMDctMzE2NS00MTFmZDI0NTYxMDQmaW5zaWQ9NTUxNg&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=2b4c5295-d3a2-6007-3165-411fd2456104&psq=magnesium+fumes+danger+prevention&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9uai5nb3YvaGVhbHRoL2VvaC9ydGt3ZWIvZG9jdW1lbnRzL2ZzLzExNDQucGRmIzp-OnRleHQ9VGhlJTIwcmVjb21tZW5kZWQlMjBhaXJib3JuZSUyMGV4cG9zdXJlJTIwbGltaXQlMjBpcyUyMDEwJTIwbWclMkZtMyxyZXNwaXJhdG9ycyUyMHNob3VsZCUyMGJlJTIwd29ybi4lMjBXZWFyJTIwcHJvdGVjdGl2ZSUyMHdvcmslMjBjbG90aGluZy4&ntb=1) might be helpful.

Comment: "Inert gas"? You don't mean nitrogen, do you? Because that isn't going to work.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm using argon

Comment: Is Mg and Ni miscible?  I have read somewhere Mg+Ni alloys can be made only by powder metallurgy, as the melted metals tend to separate.

Comment: Which particular phase?

Comment: I want to make Mg2Ni

Answer (score 8):

First off, let us assume you are using argon as the inert gas. Nitrogen is not inert to magnesium.

You may want to look at the Mg-Ni phase diagram from Ref. [1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Equilibrium-phase-diagram-of-Mg-Ni-Islam-and-Medraj-2005-Zeng-1999_fig6_221910119). The horizontal axis is atomic percent nickel, with 10% spacing between grid points. At low nickel concentrations, you have an [eutectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutectic_system) with melting point 508 °C, so you can form a melt with that composition without overheating the magnesium. If you need a higher level of nickel, you may want to start with the eutectic and incrementally add nickel and heat to "follow the shoreline".

[image]

**Reference**

1. Czerwinski, Frank. (2011). *Welding and Joining of Magnesium Alloys*. 10.5772/13947.

Comment: In order to avoid working at the extremes with one metal evaporating before the other melts, it's useful to start with an alloy very rich in the low-melting material and add it to the melt of the other metal. For example, ferromolybdenum  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromolybdenum) is created by  aluminothermic reaction, and that concentrated Mo source is then added to molten iron.